# Evitar overflow cuando hago un translateX

Tags: css, css-transform, animacion-css

Estoy diseñando una interfaz en la que necesito hacer un sidebar para mostrar un offcanvas clásico pero estoy teniendo un problema de diseño. Cuando se muestra el sidebar se tiene que mover hacia la izquierda el contenido de `main` respetando el `width` actual (ajustándose automáticamente), pero al hacer esta animación el contenido de main se desplaza completamente generando un overflow en x

```js
let sidebar = document.getElementById("side");
let main = document.getElementById("main");
let button = document.getElementById("mybutton");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('closed');
  main.classList.toggle('closed');
}, false);
```

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

main {
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid #f4c;
  flex: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform .7s;
}

main.closed {
  transform: translateX(236px);
}

aside>div {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 236px;
  transform: translateX(-236px);
  transition: transform .7s;
}

aside div.closed {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <aside>
    <div id='side'>
      sidebar
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main id='main'>
    <button id='mybutton'>
      show/hide
    </button> hola
  </main>
</div>
```

Aún no logro evitar ese overflow, ojalá puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu contenedor main se desborda porque lo estás trasladando 236 píxeles a la derecha. La propiedad `translateX` no modifica su ancho, simplemente lo mueve a la derecha, por lo que a menos que reduzcas su ancho, su `width` permanecerá igual.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, crear un contenedor que ocupará el 100% de tu pantalla + 236px, que es lo que estableciste para la barra lateral. Obviamente solo se mostrará en pantalla la parte del 100%, de manera que cuando quieras mostrar la barra lateral, agregues un margen de 236px y todo se mostrará en pantalla.

Te adjunto un demo con tu código.

```js
let sidebar = document.getElementById("side");
let main = document.getElementById("main");
let button = document.getElementById("mybutton");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('closed');
}, false);
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
.App {
  position: relative;
  left: -236px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% + 236px);
}

main {
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid #f4c;
  flex: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform .7s;
}


aside>div {
  background-color: #000000;
  position:relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: margin-left .7s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 236px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

aside div.closed {
  margin-left: 236px;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <aside>
    <div id='side'>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus nihil sunt nesciunt doloribus ullam inventore, laborum odit magnam cumque. Nostrum nihil voluptates ab dolores voluptas mollitia possimus facilis nemo consequuntur?
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main id='main'>
    <button id='mybutton'>
      show/hide
    </button> hola
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus nihil sunt nesciunt doloribus ullam inventore, laborum odit magnam cumque. Nostrum nihil voluptates ab dolores voluptas mollitia possimus facilis nemo consequuntur?
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por responder, ya había intentado una solución parecida a la que propones, el problema es cuando el sidebar tiene contenido (por ejemplo si le pones más texto) se puede ver  como el texto se va acomodando conforme el width va cambiando en la animación y quiero evitar ese efecto tan extraño

Comment: Dejame editar a ver si te doy otra alternativa.

Comment: @ReneLimon checa si esta solución te sirve. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda